# Android Json Parsing with multipartEntity

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, multipartentity

I need to parse this as an JsonArray instead of objects
but it dosent seem to work correctly.

> my output is ["{"TransactionVolume":"34","TransactionitemID":"2"}"]
>
> I need it to be [{"TransactionVolume":"34","TransactionitemID":"2"}]

this is part of my code

```
public class TransactionItem {

    public String TransactionitemID;
    public String TransactionVolume;

    public String getTransactionVolume() {
        return TransactionVolume;
    }

    public void setTransactionVolume(String transactionVolume) {
        TransactionVolume = transactionVolume;
    }

    public String getTransactionitemID() {
        return TransactionitemID;
    }

    public void setTransactionitemID(String transactionitemID) {
        TransactionitemID = transactionitemID;
    }


}

TransactionItem transactionItem = new TransactionItem();
transactionItem.setTransactionitemID(article.toString());
transactionItem.setTransactionVolume(volume.toString());


 String transitemjson = gson.toJson(transactionItem);
 JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
 ja.put(transitemjson);
 String test = ja.toString().replaceAll("\\\\\"", "\"");
```

Ja seems to be right where the output is

["{\"TransactionVolume\":\"34\",\"TransactionitemID\":\"2\"}"]

So I've tried to replace all \ with " but still the " at the begging and end.

Trimming the String doesn't seem like an good idea, but it could work. Is there any other way of doing this?

**EDIT**

This got me to the goal!

```
 ArrayList<TransactionItem> Transactionlist = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i=0; i < CompleteArticle.size(); i++) {
          String id = CompleteArticle.get(i);
          String Volume = CompleteVolume.get(i);
            TransactionItem transactionItem = new TransactionItem();
            transactionItem.setTransactionitemID(id);
            transactionItem.setTransactionVolume(Volume);
            //transactionitems.transactionitems.add(transactionItem);
            Transactionlist.add(transactionItem);
        }


  JsonElement transitemjson = gson.toJsonTree(transactionItems);
```

> Output :
>
> [{"TransactionVolume":"1","TransactionitemID":"5"},{"TransactionVolume":"3","TransactionitemID":"3"}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `JSONElement` instead of a `String`.
Replace this line:

```
String transitemjson = gson.toJson(transactionItem);
```

With this:

```
JSONElement transitemjson = gson.toJsonTree(transactionItem);
```